# VBA Excel: Combine cells with specific character to the starting cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine cells in Excel that contain a specific character with the cell above it. For example, in the screenshot

[image: here]

I want to combine column B together with the codes it relates to. I typed in the desired result in cells A74 to A81 manually.

However, I am having trouble writing a code that outputs the cells next to it but when it reaches cells with slashes ("/"), it combines the slashes with the number above it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _How_ were you able to achieve the desired result in cells `A74` to `A81`? You say is combines the `/` with the cell above it, but also that "I am trying to combine cells in Excel that contain a specific character with the cell above it" What character?

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the post to say that I had typed the desired results in manually. The specific character I was talking about was "/"

Comment: Should A67:A69 be empty, or?

Comment: That is something that will be filled in. Just empty on the example sorry. Imagine /1, /2, /3.. so on in those empty cells

Comment: Please don't post "sample data" which doesn't reflect what you're actually working with -  it just leads to people trying to figure out how to handle variability which doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

if the data are as shown: Numbers in ascending order and intermediate alphanumerics then starting from A1 you can use the formula:

***REPLACE ; WITH , ACCORDING YOUR LOCAL SETTINGS***

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B1);B1; MAX($B$1:B1) & B1)
```

And a VBA function to do the job:

```
Public Sub Combine(startCell As Range)
   Dim rc As Long, c As Long, lastrow As Long, tRng As Range, lastnum As Long
   If startCell.CountLarge > 1 Then Set startCell = startCell(1)
   With startCell.Worksheet
      lastrow = .Cells(.rows.CountLarge, startCell.Column + 1).End(xlUp).row
      Set tRng = startCell.Resize(lastrow - startCell.row + 1, 1)
   End With
   rc = tRng.rows.CountLarge
   For c = 1 To rc
      With tRng(c)
         If IsNumeric(.Offset(0, 1)) Then
            lastnum = .Offset(0, 1)
            .Value2 = lastnum
         Else
            .Value2 = lastnum & .Offset(0, 1)
         End If
      End With
   Next
End Sub

Sub tester()
   Call Combine(Me.Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is is perfect. So much more efficient than my method of putting IF and LEFT statements together. Would there be a way to turn this into a Macro at all? Ideally needed it in VBA coding to create a button

Comment: @Faraaz, now can call the vba Combine function with a parameter: the cell to begin the combination, in my example the A1.

Answer (score 0):

Place data from rows 2. Leave the first row empty or place column titles there.

Place this worksheet function to cell A2. Copy down the column.

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("/",B2)),B2,IF(ISERR(SEARCH("/",A1)),A1&B2,LEFT(A1,SEARCH("/",A1)-1)&B2))
```

That's all.